# Pubnub subscription error withing iframe only

Tags: pubnub

I get an empty error object {} attempting to subscribe to a channel when my page + javascript code is running in an iframe. It works fine when loaded directly. Channel name is the same in both cases. Any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
(function(){
    function PubSub(app,subscribe_key,channel_postfix){
        this._app = app;
        this._subscribeKey = subscribe_key;
        this._channelPostfix = channel_postfix;
        this._pubnub = PUBNUB({subscribe_key: this._subscribeKey,ssl: true});
        var test = this._pubnub;
        var test2 = test;
    };

    global.PubSub = PubSub; // global class 
    PubSub.prototype.subscribe_reactions = function (session_id){
        var self = this;
        var channel = ("reactions." + session_id);
        if (this._channelPostfix) { channel = ("" + channel + "." + (this._channelPostfix)) };
        return this._pubnub.subscribe({
            channel: channel,
            message: function(data) {
                // console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
                return self._app.transform_and_load_data().got_reaction(data);
            },
            error: function(error) { return window.alert(("Error subscribing to reactions: " + JSON.stringify(error) + " on channel " + channel + ".")); }
        });
    };

    PubSub.prototype.subscribe_foci = function (session_id){
        var self = this;
        var channel = ("foci." + session_id);
        if (this._channelPostfix) { channel = ("" + channel + "." + (this._channelPostfix)) };
        return this._pubnub.subscribe({
            channel: channel,
            message: function(data) {
                // console.log(data)
                return self._app.transform_and_load_data().got_focus_point(data);
            },
            error: function(error) { return window.alert(("Error subscribing to foci: " + JSON.stringify(error) + " on channel " + channel + ".")); }
        });
    };
    return PubSub;

})()
```

Comment: I suspect that `this._pubnub = PUBNUB({subscribe_key: this._subscribeKey,ssl: true});` is not in common scope as your subscribe call, but not sure.

Comment: Try https://jsbin.ably.io/eyofaw/2/edit and https://jsbin.ably.io/ofubek/2/edit which shows that it's certainly not an iFrame issue using a realtime connection.